# Put an auto-reference from a table into the footer

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

In Word 2007, I want to put a reference into the footer, which already exists in a table on the first page.

I made a Word template for a letter and there is a small table on the first page. It contains a date, a reference, et cetera. I need this reference (which changes every time) to be automatically shown in the footer.

Is this possible? We always forget to change the footer if we can't do it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this using Cross Reference:

1. Place the cursor in the footer where you want the reference to appear
2. Click the *Insert* tab and select *Cross-reference* [image]
3. Select the Reference type you have (numbered item, heading, etc) and you will see the available references.

[image]

I'm using Word 2010, but things should look pretty much the same as in Word 2007. I hope this helps.